# Font pack for math symbols

Tags: packages, math-fonts

Which `usepackage{}` should I use for the font in the image? Or the closest font to it

[image]

Comment: What documentclass are you using?

Comment: ```\documentclass[a4paper]{article}``` ```\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}``` ```\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}``` ```\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}``` ```\usepackage{refcount}``` ```\usepackage{tgheros}``` ```\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}```

Comment: I would reconsider the choice of font, the picture doesn't look very balanced. The letters and digits seem much heavier than the parens and some of the operators, the operators only use round ends while the digits have sharp corners and even the fraction bar doesn't really seem to fit to the weight of the operators.

Comment: You could `\usepackage{cmbright}`

Comment: I understood thank you.

Comment: Why would anyone even be using that font?

Comment: Very kind user thank you for your comment. But I am more mode happy if you give the green check mark to @Bernard,please. I hope that this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did but I couldn't handle the less than or equal symbol:) Help me please

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardplus=\mathcode`+
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecoplus}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@plus\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@plus}[2]{
  \raisebox{-0.05\height}{\scalebox{1.4}{\hspace{-0.1mm}$\m@th#1\standardplus$}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecoplus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }
\makeatother
%
\newcommand{\thickfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{1.pt}{0}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\bigfrac[3][1.0pt]{%
{\thickfrac{\hspace{#1}#2\hspace{#1}}{\hspace{#1}#3\hspace{#1}}}}
\let\oldfrac\frac
\let\frac\bigfrac
%
\begin{document}
$$\frac{(x+3)^2(x-1)}{x^2+1}\leq 0$$
\end{document}
```

And:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you wanted your math letters to be italic sans, you could `\usepackage{cmbright}`.  Unlike with the use of `mathastext`, sans Greek support is also provided here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{refcount} 
\usepackage{tgheros} 
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{(x + 3)^2(x-1)}{x^2 + 1} \le \alpha
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another alternative to the `cmbright` package is the `arev` package:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Load `mathastext`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{refcount}
 \usepackage{tgheros}
 \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
 \usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}

    \[ \frac{(x + 3)^2(x-1)}{x^2 + 1} \leq 0 \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make the +, - and = symbols slightly larger?

Comment: It is possible using the `relsize` package and typing `x\mathlarger{-}1`, &c., in the equation. However I don't see why you do do that.

Comment: How can I do this for the all page? I used Declarsize but I could not be successful.

Comment: I've just checked, and relsize seems to be messing with mathastext. Do you really need upright letters in your equations?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I need. I want it to be like the image I shared.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to increase the size for just some symbols. Maybe some TeX guru knows (if that is possible) …

Answer (score 4):

I add a MWE with the option **`kurier`**.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{(\textup{x} + 3)^2(\textup{x}-1)}{\textup{x}^2 + 1} \leq 0\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @Sebastiano :) Number 2 looks weird